# install CNTK on server

Tags: python, linux, server, openmpi, cntk

I am installing cntk on my server. (Only CPU version)
python version is 3.6.6

mpirun -V

> mpirun (Open MPI) 3.1.1

I follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-linux-python?tabs=cntkpy27) and it is ok.

> pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.7.post1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

Then, I run Python and import cntk. But there are some error as below.

> pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.7.post1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
>   Collecting cntk==2.7.post1   Downloading
>   https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.7.post1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
>   (75.1 MB)
>        |████████████████████████████████| 75.1 MB 7.9 kB/s Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17 in
>   /cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>   (from cntk==2.7.post1) (1.4.1) Requirement already satisfied:
>   numpy>=1.11 in
>   /cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>   (from cntk==2.7.post1) (1.18.2) Installing collected packages: cntk
>   Attempting uninstall: cntk
>       Found existing installation: cntk 2.7
>       Uninstalling cntk-2.7:
>         Successfully uninstalled cntk-2.7 Successfully installed cntk-2.7 (my_environment) [cnphuong@login-2.SAGA ~/pytorch]$ python
>   Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:17:58) [GCC 7.3.0] on linux
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > > import cntk /cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py_init.py:56:
> > > >         UserWarning: Unsupported Linux distribution ("centos"-"centos linux 7
> > > >         (core)). CNTK supports Ubuntu 16.04 and above, only.
> > > >         warnings.warn('Unsupported Linux distribution (%s-%s). CNTK supports
> > > >         Ubuntu 16.04 and above, only.' % (**my_distro**, **my_distro_ver**))
> > > >         /cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py_init.py:98:
> > > >         UserWarning:
> > > >
> > > > ########################################## Missing optional dependency (GPU-Specific)
>
> ##########################################    CNTK may crash if the component that depends on those dependencies is loaded.    Visit
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-Linux-Python#optional-gpu-specific-packages
>   for more information.
>
> ###################################################################################################################################### If you intend to use CNTK without GPU support, you can ignore the
>
> (likely) GPU-specific warning!
>
> #
>
> warnings.warn(WARNING_MSG_GPU_ONLY % ('GPU-Specific',
>   'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-Linux-Python#optional-gpu-specific-packages'))
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "/cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cntk._cntk_py'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cntk/**init**.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       from . import cntk_py   File "/cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       _cntk_py = swig_import_helper()   File "/cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py.py",
>   line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_cntk_py')   File "/cluster/home/cnphuong/my_environment/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: libmpi_cxx.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Comment: »» ImportError: libmpi_cxx.so.1 «« : RHEL 7, CentOS 7 → `# yum install openmpi openmpi-devel`

Comment: I loaded openmpi from the server, and I checked it with "mpirun -V"
 -> version of openmpi: Open MPI) 3.1.1

Comment: The default EL 7 openmpi is version `1.10.7`. Provides `/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1` .... Your (home built rpms?) version "3.1.1" : Probably  `/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.40`

Comment: It means that i have to use 1.x version of mpi instead of 3x as my lib .

Comment: How about `# pip install cntk` in order to build cntk with the available openmpi-3.1.1 ?

Comment: Yes. I installed openmpi version 1x and it worked. Thanks. Could you share some example with distributed cntk?

Comment: »» share some example with distributed cntk «« : Please elaborate.... ( I have absolutely no knowledge of  cntk.)

Comment: Thanks, I am try to run example, send, receive, rpc with cntk. But I did not search any document about that. I will try to read the source.